# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_csv'

Tags: python, python3, kivy

I am trying to create a Python app (using Kivy). I am at the stage where I would like to push it to my device, however I keep getting an error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_csv'
```

Here is a link to a trimmed version of the log output (trimmed to the error: https://gist.github.com/dipeshjoshi01/d3ec50995acb2e4b4f89e0c7fccb9b82) which shows this.

I've looked around and it looks like my Python wasn't installed correctly on my virtual Ubuntu device, and it is missing the "_csv.py" file. But it also looks like this can't be installed.

From what I have read online, people recommend to uninstall, then reinstall python again as the version could be corrupted. I am a bit nervous about doing this though, incase it messes up the Python that should be there.

Can anyone talk me through how I would go about getting this file back onto my device (either how I should un/reinstall Python, or an alternative way).

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm very new to Ubuntu, but looking forward to learning more about it! If it helps, I am running Python3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very limited knowledge of Python coding, but you might try executing:
'pip install csv' in a terminal. AFAIK, some missing modules have to be installed via pip. Also, you may want to go [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/) for Adrian Rosebrock's excellent "Py Image Search" website for some easy-to-understand Python tutorials. Some of them are written for the Raspbian OS (the OS that many Raspberry Pi SBC users run), but I think much of the coding used may apply to other Linux-based OSes.

delta1071